# Why is the template-parameter for std::counting_semaphore<> a ptrdiff_t?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, semaphore, c++20

Why is the template-parameter for [`std::counting_semaphore<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore) a `ptrdiff_t` and not a `size_t` ? For me there's no sense in having negative maximum semaphore counting values.

Comment: `size_t` is semantically not a count, it is a size. Moreover, both Herb, Bjarne (et al) have repeatedly spoken about how using unsigned integers for size was a mistake to begin with. Even if it _semantically_ can make sense to use unsigned integers for representing numbers such as "size" and "count", it comes with all the costs and confusion of using unsigned integers (well-defined wrap-around) as compared to the optimizer-friendly signed integers.

Comment: @dfrib add a source and that's the answer right there.

Comment: What I can say for sure is that the counter type was implementation-defined in R2 of the proposal, but the use of this type was moved to a template parameter (leaving `max` as no longer completely implementation-defined) and changed to `ptrdiff_t` specifically in R3.

Comment: Adopted proposal for for `std::ssize()` http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1227r2.html  Includes links to other similar proposals.

Comment: TRWTF is that `ptrdiff_t` is a bad name if it's used in any other context than actualy determining the difference between pointers...

Comment: ptdiff_t and size_t aren't specified in that way, but they're actually on almose any platform the data-types that fit in a general purpose register and are used because of that very often.

Comment: IMHO used->abused. Name is still out of context and confusing. And there's a reasonable consensus about that.

Comment: @JHBonarius: If there would be a consensus about that they wouldn't be wiedely used in the standard-libary for other purposes, especially size_t.

Comment: STL is 28 years old, C++ got many of their defaults wrong. [Read this paper by Bjarne himself](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1428r0.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

`size_t` is semantically not a count, it is a size. Moreover, both Herb, Bjarne (et al) have repeatedly spoken about how the existing used of unsigned integers in STL was a mistake to begin with. Even if it *semantically* can make sense to use unsigned integers for representing numbers such as "size" and "count", it comes with all the costs and confusion of using unsigned integers (well-defined wrap-around) as compared to the optimizer-friendly signed integers.

Note however that this discussion (with the "unsigned was a mistake" view supported by e.g. Bjarne, Herb, Meyers) has historically been a divider in community.

See e.g. Bjarne's [P1428R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1428r0.pdf) (*Subscripts and sizes should be signed*):

> #### The Problem
>
> [...] I will dig into the arguments and consider alternatives, but my conclusion stands:
>
> - **The original use of unsigned for the STL was a bad mistake and should be corrected (eventually)**
>
> #### Why we have unsigned subscripts in the STL
>
> As far as I remember (the STL is 25 years old so my memory may not be completely accurate) three reasons were given for the STL using unsigned types for subscripts
>
> - [...]
>
> **Basically, we were wrong on all three counts** [...]
>
> #### Span
>
> [...] This was an opportunity to start an effort to convert the STL **away from its mistaken use of unsigned for subscripts.**
>
> #### Unsigned sizes
>
> **Unfortunately, sizeof yields an unsigned** (and it would be hard to change that), but we don’t have to follow that for all types with something to do with sizes.

There are ongoing activities (e.g. [P1227R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1227r2.html): *Signed ssize() functions, unsigned size() functions*) to slowly correct this argued "mistake of the past", and particularly not blindly use the same argued mistake for new features.

Comment: There's no confusion with unsigned integers and the optimization-opportunities for signed integers are rare and practically irrelevant.

Comment: @BonitaMontero That's a very strong statement, that I read as an opinionated one. The compiler may assume there is no undefined behavior program, meaning for signed integers it can assume there is never underflow nor overflow. For unsigned integers, however, it cannot make this assumption. Saying that this is "practically irrelevant" for a compiler's optimization possibilities is not correct. W.r.t. "no confusion", read e.g. the _Problems with unsigned_ section in P1428R0. The particular problem is mixed signedness arithmetics, when there is really no good reason for unsigned to begin with.

Comment: This would happen only if you explicitly check for overfflows with statements like x + 1 < x, and that's very rare. And if you use this intentionally, the compiler shouldn't optimize around that since this "optimization" doesn't make any sense. So upcoming standards should specify that signeds wrap-around and this wouldn't induce any problems. gcc and clang are "optimizing" this way, MSVC doesn't; and this "optimization" is just a Nerd-"optimization".

Comment: `std::ptrdiff_t`  is semantically incorrect too, the count we want is not a difference of pointer... And we don't have `std::semaphore_count_t` nor `std::count_t`.

Comment: @Jarod42: ptrdiff_t and size_t are always the size of a general purpose register on systems with flat memory today, so this is usually the upper bound of the desirable value-range. It's just the name that doesn't fit, but not what's behind that data-type.

Comment: @BonitaMontero: I was referring to *"size_t is semantically not a count, it is a size."* I just pinpoint that both naming would be incorrect. Then it remains just the signed/unsigned war.

Comment: @Jarod4: Why "war" ? It absolutely makes sense that a language supplies both and that you use unsigned values where negative values don't make sense. The only opportunity where I use signed values for values which never become unsigned is when I also cast them to a floating-point-type because most FPUs don't have unsigned integer loads and the replacement-code is a bit clumsy. But then I don't declare the variables ptrdiff_t directly but cast them like this: (double)(ptrdiff_t)sztValue.

Comment: @BonitaMontero: "War" because there are no consensus for expected signess of size.

Comment: @BonitaMontero In his [2016 CppCon talk "Garbage In, Garbage Out"](https://youtu.be/yG1OZ69H_-o?t=2357), Chandler Carruth gives convincing arguments why singed integer overflow should remain undefined behavior and how it can help compiler optimizations provide significantly faster code because they can make stronger assumptions.
The linked timestamp discusses a real-world example from a bzip implementation that refutes your claim that this only has an impact for code that explicitly checks for overflows (`x + 1 < x`).